# What is the difference between COALESCE and DIVIDEs alternate result?

Tags: powerbi, dax

X=DIVIDE(A,B,0)

If there is a divide by zero error then it returns 0.

Suppose X=DIVIDE(A,B). This returns blank blank when there is divide by zero error.

Now suppose I use COALESCE(X,0) then returns 0 when X is blank.

What is the difference between COALESCE and DIVIDEs alternate result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the third argument to `DIVIDE` is just a neater way to write things.

`DIVIDE ( A, B, 0 )` is logically equivalent to `COALESCE ( DIVIDE ( A, B ), 0 )` but shorter and with fewer nested parentheses to read.

It's common to be able to achieve the same result in multiple ways.

Answer (score 1):

`COALESCE` does not do division - that's the principal difference. It's purpose is completely different. You can look at it as a series of nested `IF` statements, as `COALESCE` can take any* number of arguments.

`IF ( ISBLANK ( A ), IF ( ISBLANK ( B ), IF ( ISBLANK ( C ), D, C ), B ), A )`.

This is equivalent to `COALESCE(A, B, C, D)`.

* I'm not 100% sure about the any part, perhaps there are some limits.